# Getting error while using SQL Server database at the back end of django application

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, django, database

I'm trying to use local SQL Server database as a default database in django application. I have declared database in setting.py file as below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'Test',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'P@ssw0rd1234',
        'HOST': 'DAL1281',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
            'host_is_server': True
        },
    },
}
```

While running the server I am getting below error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made
> because the target machine actively refused it.\r\n (10061)
> (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL
> Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13
> for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [08001]
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]A network-related or
> instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
> to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
> instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
> remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
> (10061)')

I'm able to connect to database using SSMS. Also I have checked TCP/IP protocol is enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PWD',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **the latest package [**mssql-django**](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django)** to connect **Django** to **MSSQL(SQL Server)** with **SQL Server Authentication**. *I use **SQL Server 2019 Express**.

So, try this code below. ***"ENGINE"** must be **"mssql"** and **"HOST"** should be **"<server>\<instance>"** and keep it blank for **"PORT"** because there will be error if setting any port number e.g. **"2244"**, **"9877"** or even **"1433"** which is **the default port number of MSSQL**:

```py
# "settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',           # Must be "mssql"
        'NAME': 'Test',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'P@ssw0rd1234',
        'HOST': 'DAL1281\something', # <server>\<instance>
        'PORT': '',                  # Keep it empty
        # 'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```